# how to do a uniform distribution on multiple mins and maxs

Tags: r, max, distribution, min, uniform

I'm looking to get a column of multiple uniform values based on a multiple min and max values

something like this:

```
x=c(1, 5, 6, 10)

runif(1, x, x+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `runif` is vectorized, you can try the following one

```
> runif(length(x), x, x + 1)
[1]  1.054772  5.589664  6.313912 10.769576
```

Comment: In this case also equivalent to `runif(length(x)) + x`.